# Cómo mover correctamente un objeto

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas, touch

Tengo un circulo que se mueve cuando toco la pantalla el tema es que me gustaría que el circulo se mueva a la dirección que toco, no que aparezca ahí directamente. Por ejemplo tengo el circulo dibujado arriba en la pantalla y toco abajo, quiero que el circulo se mueva hasta llegar a esa posición en vez de aparecer ahí.

```
public class Juego extends SurfaceView implements View.OnTouchListener{

private Paint paint;
int radio = 100, x = 100, y = 100;

public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    paint = new Paint();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);

    invalidate();
}

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent motionEvent){

    x = (int)motionEvent.getX();
    y = (int)motionEvent.getY();

    invalidate();
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Utiliza TraslateAnimation, obtén las X e Y coordenadas iniciales de tu vista getX() y getY(). En el Down del MotionEventAction . Obten el X e Y del Touch. Y en el MotionEventAction Up. Inicia la animación de TraslateAnimation. Cuando inicializas el Objeto el constructor recibe 4 parámetros.  Los dos primeros son las X e Y posiciones iniciales, y los dos siguientes son X e Y final. Seteas el tiempo de duración en que se movera ese objeto. Puedes utilizar interpolators si quieres que se mueva a cierta velocidad en el tiempo. Haz view.startAnimation() y pasa la animacion que creaste.

Comment: Mas referencias aqui: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html

Answer (score 4):

Debes usar un `ObjectAnimator`, es la forma más fácil y practica algo como...

```
@Override
  public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent motionEvent){
   x = motionEvent.getX();
   ObjectAnimator objAnim= ObjectAnimator
                .ofFloat(view,"translationX",view.getX(),x);
   objAnim.setDuration(1000);
   objAnim.setInterpolator( new LinearInterpolator());      
   objAnim.start();
}
```

...Y replicas para el eje `Y`

Answer (score 1):

Pues ya sabes, tienes que hacer un Loop.

Tienes que coger las coordenadas finales y compararlas con las iniciales.

No puedes hacer directamente:

```
x = (int) motionEvent.getX();
y = (int) motionEvent.getY();
```

Para empezar, tienes que definir con qué velocidad se moverá. ¿Qué quieres hacer, establecer un tiempo fijo para cada vez que se haga este desplazamiento?
¿Quieres que la velocidad sea constante y el tiempo dependa de la distancia?
Yo lo que haría es crear un Loop en lugar de asignar directamente "x" e "y". Y por cada vuelta del Loop hacer que te te pinte, es decir: incrementar un poco las coordenadas de forma controlada y hacer que pinte. Y repitiendo el proceso te hará parecer una animación.

Entonces, habrá que poner una espera en este Loop, pq sino te lo hará muy rápido. Imagino que el Invalidate() fuerza a la GUI a pintar la pantalla de nuevo a partir del dato x e y que acabas de calcular.

```
int shiftX = x_final - x_inicial;
int shiftY = y_final - y_incial;
```

Con esto ya tienes los desplazamientos de X y de Y. Coge y divide por 10 cada shift y con ello ya tendrás el mini-incremento del Loop que te comentaba, de 10. Incrementa 10 veces la décima parte y tendrás el incremento entero, pero en cada pasada del Loop habrás generado coordenadas parciales, a medio camino, que te permitirán pintar el objeto, pues a medio camino.
Ten en cuenta que la división normalmente no es exacta y para la asignación de la última pasada del loop usa directamente x_final.

A ver si te funciona ;)